# C++ - std::hex não esta retornando valor hexadecimal

Tags: c++

Estou tentando desenvolver um emulador de gameboy como um desafio para mim mesmo, estou no processo de decodificar os opcodes, para isso preciso obter o valor hexadecimal dele extraído da ROM do jogo, porém ao invés de retornar um valor hex ele retorna caracteres estranhos, como o da foto:

```
    void CPU::Exec()
    {

        std::uint8_t opcode = mmu->ReadMemory(PC);

        switch (opcode) {

        case 0x0:
            cycles += 4;
            PC++;
            break;

        }

        std::cout << "Current opcode: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << opcode << std::endl;

    }
```

[image: caractere estranho]

A função `ReadMemmory` basicamente esta lendo da ROM que é basicamente um vetor de uint8_t que armazena o conteúdo da ROM

```
    bool Cartridge::Load()
    {

        std::fstream file(gamePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Could not read file" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        this->romData = std::vector<std::uint8_t>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {});

        file.close();

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O motivo é que o `cout` está tratando o tipo `std::uint8_t` como se fosse um `char` na hora de imprimir, ao invés de um `unsigned int`. Por causa disso tanto o `std::hex` quanto o `std::uppercase` não tem efeito algum. O caractere que você está vendo é o caractere da [tabela ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) correspondente ao valor do opcode lido.

Vamos mostrar isso com um programa bem simples.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::uint8_t a = 77;

    std::cout << std::hex << "O valor em é " << static_cast<unsigned int>(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa vai exibir a mensagem "O valor é M", quando o esperado seria "O valor é 4d" (4d é o valor em base 16 de 77). Como o `cout` lidou com a variável `a` como se ela fosse do tipo `char`, então exibiu o caractere correspondente ao número "77" na tabela ascii, que é a letra "M".

Para solucionar basta fazer um cast da variável a ser impressa para `unsigned int` e o valor correto em hexadecimal será impresso.

Se não quiser fazer o cast você pode usar o `printf`, já que o printf vai interpretar e imprimir o valor da variável dependendo da string de formatação que você usar e não do tipo da variável.

Com o `printf` ficaria

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::uint8_t a = 77;

    printf("O valor em é %X", a);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**

Olhei aqui no meu sistema, vendo onde o tipo `std::uint8_t` é definido, e de fato ele nada mais é do que um `typedef` de um `unsigned char`.

Comment: Eu achava que hex retornaria o valor hexadecimal de qualquer tipo

Comment: `std::dec`, `std::hex`, `std::oct`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex
"Modifies the default numeric base for **integer I/O**."
Apenas de tipos numéricos e inteiros.